# Replacing nested form items when a select changes? (Rails / AJAX / StimulusJS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I have a standard Rails app with a pre-populated nested form.  I have a select on the parent model which when the user changes the context of the nested items and they need to be cleared and re-populated.

I have been using StimulusJS and wanted to something like this:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = [ "budgetCode", "body", "template" ]

  connect() {
  }

  budget_code_changed(event) {

    document.getElementById('budget_items').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = '';


    const url = '/budget_code_items/budget?budget_code_id=' + this.budgetCodeTarget.value;

    Rails.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data) { 

        let row;
        var content = this.templateTarget.innerHTML
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.bodyTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content)
          }

      }
    })

      }

 }
```

I am getting close there - when I change the select the rows are removed.  I can manually insert a single new row with this:

```
    var content = this.templateTarget.innerHTML
    this.bodyTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content)
```

as I have a  defined with my new row structure.

The issue I seem to have is with embedding the Stimulus call inside the Rails.ajax function.  I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined errors.  I am sure this is a variable scope type issue.  Javascript is not my strong skill set here so I suspect I am missing something small here that is an easy fix.

**Related Side Question:**

At the same time in one of my template column cells I need to add some text and set the value of a hidden input from the data on that Rails.ajax call. I can likely figure that out on my own but if anyone can add to that side issue it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *fat arrow* to retain the scope so `this` remains pointed to the controller

```js
Rails.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET',
  success: (data) => {
    // now this retains to the controller
  }
})
```

By the way you can pass the parameter as follows

```js
const url = '/budget_code_items/budget'
Rails.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'budget_code_id=' + this.budgetCodeTarget.value,
  success: (data) => {
  }
})
```

See the more detailed [example](https://gorails.com/forum/populate-dropdowns-based-on-selection-with-stimulus-js#forum_post_14073) for additional controller code structuring.

Comment: Awesome - I figured it was something a simple as that.